# How to let CATransaction repeat infinitely? - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, catransaction

I have an animate function which contains `CATransaction.begin()`
I want this animation to be repeated infinitely or for a defined number of times.
How do I make that happen?

This is the animate function if you need to see the code:

```
 private func animate(views: [UIView], duration: TimeInterval, intervalDelay: TimeInterval) {

        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
            print("COMPLETED ALL ANIMATIONS")
        }

        var delay: TimeInterval = 0.0
        let interval = duration / TimeInterval(views.count)

        for view in views {
            let transform = view.transform

            UIView.animate(withDuration: interval, delay: delay, options: [.curveEaseIn], animations: {

                view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2)

            }, completion: { (finished) in

                UIView.animate(withDuration: interval, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseIn], animations: {

                    view.transform = transform

                }, completion: { (finished) in


                })
            })

            delay += (interval * 2.0) + intervalDelay
        }
        CATransaction.commit()
    }
```

Comment: What exactly you want to repeat forever?

Comment: Generally speaking there is option .repeat, but I'm not sure that it's suits for CATransaction needs.

Comment: I think all `CATransaction` is redundant there,

Answer (score 1):

I think `CATransaction` redundant there

If I understand what you want to achieve

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: interval, delay: delay, options: [.curveEaseIn, .autoreverse, .repeat], animations: { 
    self.views.forEach{$0.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2)}
}, completion: nil)
```

EDIT: Recursive function to do pulse in circles

```
func pulse(index: Int) {
    guard views.count > 0 else { return }
    let resolvedIndex = (views.count < index) ? index : 0
    let duration = 1.0
    let view = views[resolvedIndex]
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseIn,.autoreverse], animations: {
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2)
    }) { [weak self] _ in
        self?.pulse(index: resolvedIndex + 1)
    }
}
```

Comment: My program creates several views, arranges them in a circular path, and then each view animates "transform" in an ordered manner, in other words, one by one. Your piece of code made all of the views animate together and at once. What I'm trying to do is repeat this animation cycle because right now, it only occurs once.

Comment: You want them all pulsing  together after first round. Out you want them pulsing in circles?

Comment: I want them to pulse one by one, not together and I want this cycle to be repeated continuously.

Comment: .repeat makes the single view repeat the pulsing continuously and I dont want that because as I've mentioned, I'm trying to repeat the entire cycle.

Comment: It's unrational to do in one go, much better to do in recursive function

Comment: The recursive function did not work. I get the Thread1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16fcbffb0) error after running

Comment: My mistake - you had to use  `let view = views[resolvedIndex]` PS: I advice you to understand proposed solution rather then copy/past it.